# Error message trying to open rtorrent

Tags: torrent

I just installed rtorrent using Homebrew(on Macbook Air with Mavericks), but every time I try to open it I get the following error message :

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __ZNSt3tr18__detail12__prime_listE
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/libtorrent.18.dylib
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib
 in /usr/local/lib/libtorrent.18.dylib
```

This is my .rtorrent.rc file :

```
directory = ~/Downloads/
session = ~/.session/
encryption = allow_incoming, try_outgoing, enable_retry
schedule = watch_directory,5,5,load_start= ~/Downloads/*.torrent
schedule = untied_directory,5,5,stop_untied=
schedule = tied_directory,5,5,start_tied=
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the answer from: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/24132

> I ran into the same thing this week with upgrading to Mavericks. It'll fix itself if you do:

`brew reinstall libtorrent --build-from-source`

> In this case, I think the issue is that the Mavericks bottle for libtorrent is bogus, but it's the default install.

Author: bconway

Comment: `brew reinstall rtorrent --build-from-source` worked for me. Probably a different problem this time around.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I uninstalled gcc after installing rtorrent. First, try reinstalling gcc (`brew install gcc`) and see if it works. This is what I did and now it works:

```
brew uninstall rtorrent
brew install gcc
brew install rtorrent
```